# How to write code to release manged/unmanaged resources in Destructor/Dispose method

Tags: c#, destructor, finalizer, disposable

Im new to C#, I actually understand the concept of destructor and dipose method and the difference between them and how actually the GC is invoked/prevented from these operations. But when I try to understand what actually we release inside these methods, Im getting stuck.

First thing is that just defining a empty destructor or a console output wont do anything good to release the unused memory. So what should I write inside the destructor, either make the fields of the class as null or what ?. I know that GC will take care of the managed resources, so what If I faced with unmanaged resources

I usually find this familiar example all over the forums and searches but none has the clarity on what should be written to release the unused memory

```
class Test : IDisposable
{
    private bool isDisposed = false;

    ~Test()
    {
       Dispose(false);
    }

    protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
       if (disposing)
       {
          // Code to dispose the managed resources of the class
       }
       // Code to dispose the un-managed resources of the class

       isDisposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       Dispose(true);
       GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

I understand the example but what code should come in the commented lines inside the dispose method ( *// Code to dispose the managed resources of the class*  & 
 *// Code to dispose the un-managed resources of the class* ). Can some one give me a sample example that would solve my doubt

Comment: You shouldn't write any additional code in destructor, call to `Dispose(false)` is enough. After `// Code to dispose the managed resources of the class` you should dispose your managed resources (for example, call `MyManagedResourceInstance.Dispose()`). After `// Code to dispose the un-managed resources of the class` you should dispose your unmanaged resource (for example, release system handle `NativeMethods.CloseHandle(MyUnmanagedResourceHandle)`)

Comment: **Do not attempt to write a destructor**.  Writing a correct destructor is one of the hardest things to do in C# and I **strongly advise you to not do so**.  If you have an unmanaged resource that you need to manage, use a safe handle. For a list of reasons why writing a destructor correctly is hard, see https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/

Comment: It's great to be curious about how stuff works and I encourage that. But **you do not have nearly enough experience to be writing a class that tracks an unmanaged resource**. I have been writing C# programs for over a decade and was on the compiler team and I have never written a destructor except for test cases. I do not attempt to write classes that track unmanaged resources, and I encourage you to similarly not make the attempt.

Comment: I read the question, and was just about to to tear out a comment... Then i looked at the comments, woah, fully summed up

Answer (score 3):

> I understand the example but what code should come in the commented
>   lines

Look, every managed resource(i.e. allocated by .Net that uses no unmanaged resource under the hood) is freed using `GC` and does not need no disposal at all. All the disposal thing is about `unmanaged memory` those who were allocated via Win32 API calls or any unmanaged external code.

Now to answer your question, the answer is you have to put the code to release those unmanaged objects inside `Dispose`, based on the external code or API that you are using, there should be a way(e.g. method) to release the memory.

There may be another question, now that only unmanaged code should be disposed why there is a section to dispose managed resources?
That's because that managed resource relies internally on an unmanaged resource, by calling the `Dispose` you are freeing that memory, the managed code handled the release code for you (wrapped in `Dispose`). example of this could be `FileStream`

Comment: @vasily.sib, tnx for comment, edited my post, I meant pure managed objects, no disposal needed, right?

Comment: As a general rule, any class that implements `IDisposable` should be disposed ([except tasks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/)).  If the class instance is being accessed transiently, this means wrapping it in a `using block`.  If the instance is a member of a class which shares a lifetime with that class, that containing class should implement `IDisposable`, with the `Dispose` method being used to dispose any `IDisposable` members.  Note that none of this requires you to write a destructor.